# Shallow rendering a component which depends on TweenLite

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, gsap

I'm trying to make a simple unit test with a React component but I keep getting:

```
C:\work\portfolio\node_modules\gsap\TweenMax.js:13
    import TweenLite, { TweenPlugin, Ease, Power0, Power1, Power2, Power3, Power4, Linear } from "./TweenLite.js";
           ^^^^^^^^^
```

Which is an error with an import of one of children's of 'App' components 3rd party libraries.

```
import React from "react";
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import App from "./App";

fit("renders without crashing", () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<App />);
});
```

app.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import ChronologyGraph from "./chronology/ChronologyGraph";
import { nodeTypes, milestones } from "../staticData";

const App = () => (
  <ChronologyGraph
    width="700"
    height="800"
    nodeSize={10}
    milestones={milestones.reverse()}
    columns={nodeTypes}
  />
);

export default App;
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "portfolio",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "gsap": "^2.0.1",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
    "react-fontawesome": "^1.6.1",
    "react-scripts": "^1.1.5",
    "react-transition-group": "^2.4.0",
    "typeface-lato": "0.0.54",
    "typeface-roboto": "0.0.54",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "lint": "eslint src",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "testCov": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom --coverage",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "enzyme": "^3.4.4",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.2.0",
    "eslint": "^4.19.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.9.1",
    "prettier-eslint": "^8.8.2"
  }
}
```

I couldn't find any similar examples online, am I supposed to somehow mock the import of a child? I thought 'shallow' render wouldn't import children and thus children's imports

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Can you share the error message?  `shallow` doesn't render the children but the children and dependencies are still `import`-ed.

Comment: `Test suite failed to run

    C:\work\portfolio\node_modules\gsap\TweenMax.js:13
    import TweenLite, { TweenPlugin, Ease, Power0, Power1, Power2, Power3, Power4, Linear } from "./TweenLite.js";
           ^^^^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` - this is the exact error message, 'unexpected identifier' in one of 3rd party libraries, do you know how can I mock that import?

Comment: can you share `App.js` and your `package.json`?

Comment: have you added "transform" and "babel-jest" in your package.json ' ?

Comment: @brian-lives-outdoors added

Comment: @Higeath weird.  Looks like you used create-react-app to bootstrap and haven't ejected.  Since you are using create-react-app it's easy to create a mock for `gsap`, just add mock code to a file at `src/__mocks__/gsap.js`...you shouldn't have to mock it though.  I set up a test environment with your `package.json` and imported `TweenMax` and didn't have a problem running `npm test`.  You might try deleting your package.json, lock files, node_modules and re-running `npm install`

Comment: @brian-lives-outdoors I've tried redownloading packages that did not work, could you give a sample of your setup that works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(enzyme maintainer here)

Third party modules should be transpiled prepublish - since it's not safe to run babel on node_modules, and since node doesn't support `import`. You have basically these options:

1. file an issue on `gsap` so they properly transpile prepublish
2. configure babel to exclude node_modules (the default) but to *include* this module
3. configure jest to mock out `gsap` with something else

Comment: Thank you, would you mind giving me a simple example of mocking that gsap import? I have tried multiple times now with no avail

Comment: I believe it'd be `jest.mock('gsap', () => whateverMockYouWant)`; but you'd have to check the jest documentation

Answer (score 0):

Following @ljharb 3rd option:

If you read [Jest documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks) you can simply mock GSAP creating a file in `__mocks__` directory.

Let's say you are importing TweenMax and you want to use `to` method:

```js
import { TweenMax } from "gsap/TweenMax";
```

Add two files into the **mocks** directory. TweenLite can be empty.

```
.
└── __mocks__
    └── gsap
        └── TweenLite.js 
        └── TweenMax.js
```

```js
module.exports = {
  TweenMax: class{
    static to(selector, time, options) {
      return jest.fn();
    }
  }
}
```

You've successfully mock your `TweenMax.to` method.

#### Timelines are different

Because timeline works on instances of a class the mock should be done this way:

```js
import { TimelineMax } from "gsap/TimelineMax";
```

Again, add two files into the **mocks** directory. TweenLite can be empty.

```
.
└── __mocks__
    └── gsap
        └── TweenLite.js 
        └── TimelineMax.js
```

```js
module.exports = {
  TimelineMax: class {
    constructor(){
      this.to = jest.fn().mockReturnThis();
    }
  }
};
```

Use `mockReturnThis()` to be able to chain methods.