# Mocking TimelineMax and TweenMax modules in Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, gsap

I'm trying to mock my import with animations, but I keep getting

```
● Test suite failed to run

    C:\work\portfolio\node_modules\gsap\TweenMax.js:13
    import TweenLite, { TweenPlugin, Ease, Power0, Power1, Power2, Power3, Power4, Linear } from "./TweenLite.js";
           ^^^^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

The error is from one of the imports from my file.

App.js

```
const App = () => (
  <ChronologyGraph
    width="700"
    height="800"
    nodeSize={10}
    milestones={milestones.reverse()}
    columns={nodeTypes}
  />
);

export default App;
```

inside of ChronologyGraph I import my component ProjectNode which imports another file I made animation.js and inside of animation.js I import

```
import { TimelineMax, Power0 } from "gsap/TweenMax";
import { TweenMax } from "gsap/TweenMaxBase";
```

Which are causing the error above, I want to either mock this gsap library or just my animation.js

App.test.js

```
import React from "react";
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import App from "./App";

fit("renders without crashing", () => {
  jest.mock('../animation.js');
  jest.mock('gsap/TweenMaxBase');
  jest.mock('gsap/TweenMax');

  const wrapper = shallow(<App />);
});
```

And here are all the mocks I've tried without any success

Answer (score 2):

Coming late to this, but sharing because the solution is very simple. (I've already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557424/1498118) as well)

If you read [Jest documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks) you can simply mock GSAP creating a file in `__mocks__` directory.

## Mocking TweenMax

Let's say you are importing TweenMax and you want to use `to` method:

```js
import { TweenMax } from "gsap/TweenMax";
```

Add two files into the **mocks** directory. TweenLite can be empty.

```
.
└── __mocks__
    └── gsap
        └── TweenMax.js
        └── TweenLite.js
```

```js
module.exports = {
  TweenMax: class{
    static to(selector, time, options) {
      return jest.fn();
    }
  }
}
```

You've successfully mock your `TweenMax.to` method.

## Mocking TimelineMax

Because TimelineMax works on instances of a class the mock should be done this way:

```js
import { TimelineMax } from "gsap/TimelineMax";
```

Again, add two files into the **mocks** directory. TweenLite can be empty.

```
.
└── __mocks__
    └── gsap
        └── TweenLite.js 
        └── TimelineMax.js
```

```js
module.exports = {
  TimelineMax: class {
    constructor(){
      this.to = jest.fn().mockReturnThis();
    }
  }
};
```

Use `mockReturnThis()` to be able to chain methods.

Comment: Hi, please, where you put the directory. I still have error

Comment: @OscarE.Alvarado, the *mocks* directory should stay at the same level as `node_modules` folder. See https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#mocking-node-modules

Comment: Hi, thx for answed. Try placing the folder __mocks__ as it say here "if the module you are mocking is a Node module (e.g.: lodash), the mock should be placed in the __mocks__ directory adjacent to node_modules "(extract of jestjs.io), but I still have the error 'Cannot tween a null target.'

Comment: Make sure you are mocking the right module. The `import TweenMax` module `from "gsap"` requires a different mock from the one `from "gsap/all"`. Which module are you mocking? Can you make sure the path of the mocked module in the `__mocks__` directory is the same of the path in the `from` you are invocking?

Comment: I am somewhat confused, create a thread with the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59093137/error-cannot-tween-a-null-target-in-unit-test-with-gsap-tweenmax-jest-and-vuejs

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the UMD version instead, like:

```
import TweenLite from "gsap/umd/TweenLite"
```

Answer (score 0):

please update your jest config:

```
"transform": {
  "\\.js$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest"
}
```

and install babel-jest.
Further if your issue wouldn't get resolved then share your jest config and we don't usually mock imports.

Comment: I probably should have mentioned, the project was built using react-scripts, so it comes with babel-jest and jest is preconfigured