# Error Cannot tween a null target in Unit test with GSAP-TweenMax, Jest and VueJs

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs, gsap

I have an error when trying to perform a unit test with Jest on a component in VueJs that has an animation made with `TweenMax GSAP`.
The error is: `Cannot tween a null target.`

in ztButton.spec.js

```
jest.mock('gsap/TweenMax')

it('Component must to emit event on click', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(ztButton)
    const spy = sinon.spy()
    wrapper.setMethods({ clickButton: spy })
    wrapper.find('.zt-button').trigger('click')
    expect(spy.called).toBe(true)
  })
```

in my project directory

[image: in my project directory]

in TweenMax.js of mock directory

```
module.exports = {
  TweenMax: class {
    static to(selector, time, options) {
      return jest.fn()
    }
  }
}
```

in test directory

[image: in test directory]

There is something I do not understand, or that I am not doing well. Something confused.

Update:
This is what I do to generate an animation in my component and is invoked in mounted

```js
mounted() {
    this.componentId = this._uid
    this._addButtonRipple()
  },
methods: {
    _addButtonRipple() {
      const $button = this.$refs.button
      $button.addEventListener('click', event => {
        const rect = $button.getBoundingClientRect(),
          x = event.clientX - rect.left,
          y = event.clientY - rect.top
        let $ripple = $button.querySelector('.zt-button-ripple')
        TweenMax.set($ripple, {
          x: x,
          y: y,
          scaleX: 0,
          scaleY: 0,
          opacity: 1
        })
        TweenMax.to($ripple, 1.5, {
          scaleX: 1,
          scaleY: 1,
          opacity: 0,
          ease: Expo.easeOut
        })
      })
    },
    clickButton(event) {
      this.$emit('click', event)
      this.isRipple = true
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.isRipple = false
      }, 300)
    }
}
```

in computed

```js
computed: {
    listeners() {
      return {
        ...this.$listeners,
        click: event => this.clickButton(event)
      }
    }
```

in html tags

```html
<button v-on="listeners"></button>
```

this is the configuration of my file jest.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  verbose: true,
  moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'jsx', 'json', 'vue'],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.vue$': 'vue-jest',
    '.+\\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss|svg|png|jpg|ttf|woff|woff2)$':
      'jest-transform-stub',
    '^.+\\.jsx?$': 'babel-jest'
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/'],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1',
    '^src/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1',
    '^src/component/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/components/atomic/$1'
  },
  snapshotSerializers: ['jest-serializer-vue'],
  testMatch: [
    '**/tests/unit/components/atomic/**/**/*.spec.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)|**/__tests__/*.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)'
  ],
  testURL: 'http://localhost/'
}
```

Comment: Can you add the line of the component that generates the issue? is sufficient just the import statement of the GSAP libraries and the GSAP methods you are using.

Comment: the error is here code line: wrapper.find('.zt-button').trigger('click') in ztButton.spec.js file (ztButton.spec.js:101:32)

Comment: I see, but that's not the issue, the problem is in the callback you run when the button is clicked. If you want to get help you should add that script to your question, otherwise we don't know what you are really doing with TweenMax.

Comment: update the post

Comment: Is the information enough or do you need more to add it?

Comment: are you using the standard Jest configuration or have you changed it? It looks like it's not looking anymore for the `__mocks__` folder

Comment: add the config for file jest.config.js to the post

Comment: Sorry, I cannot seem to find what's wrong. -_-! I hope someone can throw some light on this...

Comment: Yes, this is something weird. But I will keep trying to find a solution. Thanks for the help here.

Answer (score 1):

`Cannot tween a null target` means that TweenMax methods are not mocked. Infact you are mocking just `TweenMax.to` method.

Please update your mock this way:

```
module.exports = {
  TweenMax: class {
    static to(selector, time, options) {
      return jest.fn()
    }
    static set(selector, options) {
      return jest.fn()
    }
  }
}
```

Let me know if that fixes it.

Comment: Update the mock, but the error persists. I think he is not detecting the mock. In my import there is one more class of 'gsap' which is Expo

Comment: can you remove `jest.mock('gsap/TweenMax')` from the top of your test? I'd like to know if that's forcing Jest to bypass the mock. See https://jestjs.io/docs/en/bypassing-module-mocks